# /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++ /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++

Tags: linux, assembly, linker, g++, 32bit-64bit

why am i getting this error?

```
g++ -m32 func.o test.o -o prgram

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libstdc++.a when searching for -lstdc++
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

my code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
  2 
  3 
  4 extern "C" int calcsum(int a, int b, int c);
  5 
  6 int main(int argc,char* argv[])
  7 {
  8     int a = 10;
  9     int b = 20;
 10     int c = 30;
 11     int sum = calcsum(a,b,c);
 12 
 13     printf("a: %d", a);
 14     printf("b: %d", b);
 15     printf("c: %d", c);
 16     printf("sum: %d", sum);
 17     return 0;
 18 }
 19
```

```
 1 section .text
  2     global _start
  3 _start:
  4 global _calcsum
  5 _calcsum:
  6 
  7     push ebp
  8     mov ebp, esp
  9 
 10     mov eax, [ebp+8]
 11     mov ecx, [ebp+12]
 12     mov edx, [ebp+16]
 13 
 14     add eax, ecx
 15     add eax, edx
 16 
 17     pop ebp
 18     ret
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are building a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system (because you used the `-m32` flag), but have not installed 32-bit versions of the development libraries.

If you're on Ubuntu, try:

```
sudo apt install gcc-multilib g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386
```

As for your assembly file, it can't work as-is. `start` will be defined by the cpp file, so remove it from the asm file. Next, remove the underscore from `_calcsum`. When building ELF binaries, function names do not start with an underscore:

```
section .text
global calcsum
calcsum:

    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, [ebp+8]
    mov ecx, [ebp+12]
    mov edx, [ebp+16]

    add eax, ecx
    add eax, edx

    pop ebp
    ret
```

Build that as a 32-bit ELF object file with:

```
nasm -felf32 func.s -o func.o
```

Comment: im getting the undefined reference to 'calcsum' error now. My assembly code is as follows :

Comment: 1 section .text
  2 global calcsum
  3 calcsum
  4 
  5     push ebp
  6     mov ebp, esp
  7 
  8     mov eax, [ebp+8]
  9     mov ecx, [ebp+12]
 10     mov edx, [ebp+16]
 11 
 12     add eax, ecx
 13     add eax, edx
 14 
 15     pop ebp
 16     ret
 17 
~                                                                               
~

Comment: @Hex Updated answer again.